# php 5.6 mail and SSL

Tags: email, openssl, pear

I found myself unable to send mails since I upgraded to php5.6.

```
$to = "Test1 <*******@gmail.com>";
$body = "Hi,\n\n this is just test email";

$headers = array(
    'From' => '*******@gmail.com',
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => 'test email'
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
    'host' => 'smtp.sendgrid.com',
    'port' => '587',
    'auth' => 'login',
    'username' => '*****',
    'password' => '*****',
));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo $mail->getMessage();
} else {
    echo "<p> Message successfully sent!</p>";
}
```

> login authentication failure [SMTP: STARTTLS failed (code: 220, response: Begin TLS negotiation now)]

If I use my Gmail account with this code, i get an error too

```
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',array (
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'port' => '465',
    'auth' => 'login',
    'username' => '******@gmail.com',
    'password' => '*******'
));
```

> authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 534, response: 5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 5.7.14 then try again. 5.7.14 Learn more at 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 jz4sm22875767wjb.16 - gsmtp)]

I have an oid application running with ZF1, and I found that there was a problem on this call Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp :

`stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->_socket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT)`

I've read that some changes had been made in php 5.6 concerning OpenSSL, but I don't know what changes I need to do.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this issue? I am going through the same issue..thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same trouble and stumbled upon the solution, and these are clearly related to changes in PHP 5.6 (which I'm not all together happy about).

1. The verify_peer and verify_peer_name are now by default set to true - requiring an extra level of security between the two machines involved in a streamed port. I don't want this when I'm dealing with SMTP, the STARTTLS encryption is enough for me. So turn these off I added some code to the Net/SMTP.php file

   $options = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer_name' => false, 'verify_peer' => false));

   $result = $this->_socket->connect($this->host, $this->port, $persistent, $timeout, $options);
2. The socket timeout default specified in php.ini is not being used by this function. So I changed the default in 'smtp.php' to:

   $timeout = 60; // previously null;

Hope that helps somebody else. Cheers Murray

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is kinda old but I will leave the answer here, maybe someone else will find it useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34090707/5639805